# Order of elements in strptime

Tags: c, time.h

I am trying to use `strptime(buf, &pattern,&result)` to convert `char[]` containing date into `tm` structure.

I am using function like this:

```
if(strptime(buf, &pattern,&result) == NULL)
   {
      printf("\nstrptime failed\n");
...
```

and everything works if my variables are defined like this:

```
char buf[] = "26/10/2011";
char pattern[] = "%d/%m/%y";
struct tm result;
```

but if I change them into:

```
char buf[] = "2011/26/10";
char pattern[] = "%y/%d/%m";
struct tm result;
```

I get "strptime failed". Notice, that I have only put year in the beginning (both in `buf` and `pattern`).

Help appreciated. My final target is to convert string in this format: `2011-10-26T08:39:21`

Comment: Are you sure you copied the code correctly here? The variable `pattern` should not be using the address-of operator in the call to `strptime`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's because the lower case `%y` is for the two-digit year *within* the century. Try changing it to uppercase `%Y` and it will work okay. You can see this from the following program:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <time.h>
int main (void) {
    char buf[] = "26/10/2011";
    char pattern[] = "%d/%m/%y";
    struct tm result;
    if (strptime (buf, pattern, &result) == NULL) {
        printf("strptime failed\n");
        return -1;
    }
    printf ("%d\n", 1900 + result.tm_year);
    return 0;
}
```

This outputs `2020`, meaning that the year is being read as just the `20` portion of `2011`, with the remainder being ignored. If you use upper-case `%Y`, it outputs the correct `2011` instead.

Code that generates the conversion error using the reversed format:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <time.h>
int main (void) {
    char buf[] = "2011/10/26";
    char pattern[] = "%y/%m/%d";
    struct tm result;
    if (strptime (buf, pattern, &result) == NULL) {
        printf("strptime failed\n");
        return -1;
    }
    printf ("%d\n", 1900 + result.tm_year);
    return 0;
}
```

will work fine (ie, output `2011`) when you change the `pattern` value to `"%Y/%m/%d"`.

Comment: aaah, such a typo... I hate it. Just to make sure, is it ok, that I get `tm_mon:  9` instead of 10?

Comment: It's in the standard: `int tm_mon Month of year [0,11]`. So January is `0`, not `1`.

Comment: @cnicutar [here](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/iadthelp/v7r0/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.etools.iseries.langref.doc/rzan5mst273.htm) I have found "Month [1-12]."...

Comment: @AdamPierzchała That's for `strptime`. I was talking about `struct tm` (the same you were talking about in your previous comment).

Answer (score 0):

Using my own 'strptime' and 'timestamp' commands, I get:

```
$ strptime -T '%y/%d/%m' 2011/26/11
strptime: failed to convert <2011/26/11> using format <%y/%d/%m>
$ strptime -T '%Y/%d/%m' 2011/26/11
1322294400 = 2011/26/11
$ strptime -T '%d/%m/%y' 26/11/2011
1606377600 = 26/11/2011
$ timestamp 1322294400 1606377600
1322294400 = Sat Nov 26 00:00:00 2011
1606377600 = Thu Nov 26 00:00:00 2020
$
```

(Time zone here is US/Pacific, currently UTC-7.)

Note that the `'%d/%m/%y'` format generates a date in 2020, not in 2011.